# Field has incomplete type - linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

This does compile... *(.h file)*

```
template<class T> class Entry {

private:
    string mykey;
    T myvalue;
    Entry mylinked; // Error: field has incomplete type

public:
    Entry(string key, T value);
    void setValue(T value);
    void setLinked(Entry linked);
    Entry getLinked();
    T getValue();
    string getKey();
};
```

Why does this not compile? Pointer issues... how should I fix this?

Comment: We are very confused.  What do you mean by "not work"?  Please add clarification to your post (not in comments).

Comment: Neither of them should really work, for the same reason. Better post an MCVE.

Comment: Are you missing a pointer in there somewhere?  Unless your linked list is array based, there probably should be a pointer to a link field.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews sorry, the first one actually does not work..... can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @juanchopanza sorry, the first one actually does not work..... can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can't have member data of the same type as its own type. Besides, you even missed the template parameter `Entry<T>`. If anything you can have a pointer/reference to another Entry, but not an instance.

Comment: @aslg The template parameter isn't needed.

Comment: Why you cannot have Entry contain an Entry. Think of it like recursion. Entry contains an Entry which contains an Entry which contains an Entry which contains an Entry which contains an Entry which contains an Entry... and this will go on long past the cows coming home. Practically, this means Entry has infinite size. If I had a computer that supported infinitely sized data types... wow. Next step would be acquiring infinite monkeys and getting in on some of that Shakespeare fat cash!

Answer (score -1):

Both classes are erroneous with several mistakes.

The reason why you do not receive a compilation error for `Example` is that you do not instantiate the templated class `Example`. Just add `Example<int> a;` somewhere below and see the compilation errors.

Comment: but what are the mistakes? (I'm new to c++, if this wasn't obvious by now)

Comment: The first mistake is that `Entry` is a templated class, so the field declaration `Entry mylinked` is invalid.

Comment: @AndreyNasonov It has nothing to do with templates.

Comment: okay, I am aware, that is what the error says... how do I go about fixing this? How can I make a linked list of templates classes (each node having the same type in the template)

Comment: The second mistake is that you make an infinite recursive inclusion. Seems you wanted to use a pointer `Entry<T> *mylinked`.

Comment: You don't need to say `Entry<T>` inside the `Entry` definition. `Entry` is fine.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I'm too pedantic.